# Finding non printable ASCII characters in an ASCII file in C

Tags: c, ascii

I am trying to check over an ASCII file for occurrences of non printable characters (not including ASCII codes 10 or 13). The general idea is that this program checks over the inputted file to make sure it meets the format requirements, one of which is using only printable ASCII characters. Currently my code looks something like this:

```
FILE *input_check;
int current_line = 1;
int current_char;

/* opens a new file stream*/
input_check = fopen(filename, "r");

/* Gets the first character*/
current_char = fgetc(input_check);

while (current_char != EOF) {
    if (current_char == 10 || current_char == 13) ++current_line;

    if (current_char < 32 && current_char != 10 && current_char != 13) {
        printf("Found non-printable character with ASCII code %d on line %d 
                    \n", current_char, current_line);
    }

    current_char = fgetc(input_check);
}

fclose(input_check);
```

I have tried putting tabs into the ASCII file to catch them, but the input stream treats them as spaces and any consecutive white spaces as one character. Is there a way to make sure that every character is inputted with its original ASCII code?

Comment: The problem sounds to me in the way you "putting" the characters into the file, not in the code.

Comment: C has `isprint(current_char)` function. `fgetc` has the declaration `int fgetc(FILE *stream);`, there's no second parameter.

Comment: Don't forget ASCII 127 is a non-printable character (Delete). While there is nothing wrong with using numerical comparisons, don't use *magic numbers*, instead use the character itself, e.g. `if (current_char < ' ' && current_char != '\r' ...` is much more readable than 32, 10, 13 (which sounds more like a football audible than coding) The header `ctype.h` makes character classification much easier `:)`

Comment: Don't use a programming editor, it converts a tab key press into spaces.

Comment: What is `fgetc(input_check,"%1c")`?

Comment: Or, at least know where the setting is that controls whether tab-characters or spaces will be entered. Most (worthwhile) editors have those settings on the page where you can choose tab-size, and indention rules.

Comment: @AndrewHenle - that looks like a *field-width* modifier to a character *conversion-specifier* for `scanf` that has been tacked onto the end of `fgetc` just for good measure, despite the prototype being `int fgetc(FILE *stream);`. It's also an indication that compiler output is being completely ignored...

Comment: @AndrewHenle I was messing around with other functions (fscanf) and just forgot to change that function call back, editted

Answer (score 1):

So, one way you could do it considering it's C it's reading the file as a binary. 
Read each character as they come this way:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) { 
FILE *fileptr;
int current_char;
int current_line = 0;
int i;

fileptr = fopen(argv[1], "rb");         


while (fread(&current_char, 1, 1, fileptr) == 1) {
    if (current_char == 10 || current_char == 13) ++current_line;

    if (current_char < 32 && current_char != 10 && current_char != 13) {
        printf("Found non-printable character with ASCII code %d on line %d 
                    \n", current_char, current_line);
    }


}  
fclose(fileptr); 
return 0;
}
```

If i'm not absurdely wrong this will keep working because each character is one byte. And you will read each character from the file one byte at a time.
If it doesn't work is there anyway the file could be rewritten in binary mode?

Comment: `fread` takes a pointer to char as the first argument, and the loop will run forever, as current_char will never be equal EOF.

Comment: Oops editing it out, i wrote his logic on top of mine and forgot to use filelen
Thanks @KamilCuk

Comment: Anyway, isn't `while (fread(&current_char, 1, 1, fileptr) == 1)` simplier? For example, If another process removes the file while your program is running, this will loop through the last read char.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, @KamilCuk and yes it is simpler.

Thanks for pointing it out. Editing

Comment: Just a note -- there isn't any difference reading characters from a file one-byte at a time with `fgetc` or `fread`. Neither functions care if the byte is a binary byte or a character byte -- it's just a byte.

Comment: As you are reading binary now, there is no CRLF translation and on DOS/Windows you will count lines twice.

Comment: The ++current_line code looks wrong to me. In windows, where you have both characters to indicate a 'newline', the increment will happen twice per newline, so the reported line won't be correct. (same line of code is in the original question, and perhaps it's outside the question's scope)

Comment: Implementing this code gives the same result as just using  _**'fgetc'**_

Comment: @Alex didn't even notice that it was just copy paste of the internal logic but yes.

Comment: I would use `\r` and `\n` instead of `13` and `10`.